# How to fix the awkwardly written for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to find a name from a website on basis of "street number" and "address" performing reverse search. It is working good for a single search.Firstly, the script should pick "A1" from the "search_post" list to put it in the "street search box" in the browser, then it should pick the "B1" from the "search_address" list to put it in the "address search box" in the browser. My script works good for the first search but when the first loop goes for the second item it takes A1 again instead of A2 and the second loop picks the right item which is B2 in this case. To be more specific, first time it takes A1, B1 but second time it takes A1, B2 in lieu of A2, B2. How can i fix this loop so that it picks items parallelly.

```
A1. 8227  B1. FINDLAY ST
A2. 6330  B2. LAUTREC DR
```

Here is the script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

search_post = ['8227','6330 ']
search_address = ['FINDLAY ST','LAUTREC DR']

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://hcad.org/quick-search/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

for item in search_post:
    for elem in search_address:
        driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
        driver.find_element_by_id("s_addr").click()
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'stnum')))
        driver.find_element_by_name('stnum').send_keys(item)
        driver.find_element_by_name('stname').send_keys(elem)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Search']").click()
        driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("quickframe"))
        element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='data']/table//th")
        print(driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].childNodes[2].textContent", element).strip())

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Splitting your text into paragraphs would go a long way to making your question easier to understand.

Comment: Forgive my linguistic difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the python `zip` method. Change your loop start from

```
for item in search_post:
    for elem in search_address:
```

to

```
for item, elem in zip(search_post, search_address)
```

What `zip` basically does is create a pair wise tuple of elements and put then in an array. Below is a sample execution

```
>>> zip([1,2],[3,4])
[(1, 3), (2, 4)]
```

**Edit 9-Aug:**

As @JeffC, suggested a simpler way would be to use just the index. There are multiple ways to do this but for simplicity sake i will list the index one too. Change below

```
for item in search_post:
    for elem in search_address:
```

to

```
i = 0
while i < len(search_post):
  item, elem = search_post[i], search_address[i]
  i += 1
  ....rest of your code...
```

Comment: Thanks Tarun Lalwani, for your answer. It fixes the for loop issue. One last thing- how can i reuse the already opened browser after collecting the first information instead of opening a new one?

Comment: If this is your full code, I don't see any reason for a new browser being opened. Is it opening a new tab? Because your driver launch and quite are outside loop.

Comment: I've got another issue sorted.

Comment: @Shahin, share that info in the comment, so if someone else has a similar issue then can learn from it

Comment: What i did to fix that can be seen following the link "https://www.dropbox.com/s/kw71wircwbj5zv8/rectified%20one.txt?dl=0"

Comment: This seems like a more complicated answer than just looping some counter, `i`, over the number of inputs you have and then inside the loop referencing `search_post[i]` and `search_address[i]`. This can be easily expanded to handle n number of data elements with minimal code changes.

Comment: @JeffC, please follow the link again to see whether it is what you meant. I've updated it already.

Comment: @Shahin Yes, that's what I was referring to. It's not that this answer is wrong, it's just that I think there is an easier solution.

Comment: Appreciate that. Much easier to use as well. Thanks.

Comment: kudos on actually reading the wall of text that the question is